# How to read integer values from a textfile and count the of occurrence of each value in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

i would like to read the from a text file shown below, loop through each individual digit and determine which digit occurs the maximum number of times. How can I go about it in pyspark.
Here is the txt file

```
1.4142135623 7309504880 1688724209 6980785696 7187537694 8073176679 7379907324 7846210703 8850387534 3276415727 3501384623 0912297024 9248360558 5073721264 4121497099 9358314132 2266592750 5592755799 9505011527 8206057147 0109559971 6059702745 3459686201 4728517418 6408891986 0955232923 0484308714 3214508397 6260362799 5251407989 6872533965 4633180882 9640620615 2583523950 5474575028 7759961729 8355752203 3753185701 1354374603 4084988471 6038689997 0699004815 0305440277 9031645424 7823068492 9369186215 8057846311 1596668713 0130156185 6898723723 5288509264 8612494977 1542183342 0428568606 0146824720 7714358548 7415565706 9677653720 2264854470 1585880162 0758474922 6572260020 8558446652 1458398893 9443709265 9180031138 8246468157 0826301005 9485870400 3186480342 1948972782 9064104507 2636881313 7398552561 1732204024 5091227700 2269411275 7362728049 5738108967 5040183698 6836845072 5799364729 0607629969 4138047565 4823728997 1803268024 7442062926 9124859052 1810044598 4215059112 0249441341 7285314781 0580360337 1077309182 8693147101 7111168391 6581726889 4197587165 8215212822 951848847
```

Comment: In your text file,whether each number in single line or all numbers in same line? As data provided above, seems that all numbers are in same line.

Comment: The numbers are in a single line

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve for a single line or multiple lines in a text file, first eliminate all the special characters from the file, and then you need to get pair RDD (digits in text file as key) .

Bellow is the pseudo-code for it,

```
strRDD = df.flatMap(lambda line : list(str(line.value)))\
        .filter(lambda digit :  digit.isalnum())\
        .map(lambda digit : (int(digit), 1))\
        .reduceByKey(lambda a, b : a + b).max(lambda x : x[1])

print(strRDD)
```

Output for your text file is :(8, 113)

Answer (score 0):

//Using RDD's - This will be better for your scenario.

load data using text file then use flatMap (since you said all numbers in single line) to split using space as delimiter. Then convert each number from string to float as some of your numbers are float. Now make RDD pair( number as key and value as one for each number). Using reduceBykey aggregate total count of each number and then sort by value using sortBy in descending order.

```
data = sc.textFile("your file path")

numcount = data.flatMap(lambda x: x.split( )).map(lambda x: (float(x),1)).reduceByKey(lambda a,b:a+b).sortBy(lambda x: x[1],ascending = False)

for i in numcount.collect(): print (i)
```

// Using DataFrames:

## since you said all numbers in single line I am reading as text to get

all values into single column. Then creating new column and splitting the column to list with space as delimiter using split function. Then exploding the list to get each number into a row.

## Now drop old column using drop function

## Now using groupBy, count functions you can count each number how many times it show's up. Also using sort in descending order you can find order wise.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

numcount = spark.read.text("your file path").withColumn('new', explode(split('value',' '))).drop('value')

numcount.groupBy('new').agg(count('new').alias('counts')).sort(desc('counts')).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from a dataframe with the data you can do:

```
df = df.groupby("digit").count().sort("count")
```

This code returns the most repeated values. After that you can show this values and get the most repèated value with:

```
df.show()
df.limit(1).show()
```